# Is there any way to reset Mac terminal environment to factory settings?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-catalina

My Mac has gotten very messy over the years while doing various things via the Terminal. Is there any way to reset it to factory settings without resetting my Mac entirely? (e.g. uninstall all packages, reset PATH variables, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you haven't changed anything outside your home folder, and that you're using the default shell, you can reset the shell to its defaults by running this command:

rm -i ~/.profile ~/.bash*

and you can reset the Terminal application by deleting this file:

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist

Quit Terminal and relaunch.