# Factory reset mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Looks like I've messed up my terminal really badly.

Im trying simple commands like `ls`, `cd` but I get:

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

No `brew` commands are found either.

I have tried following [Is there any way to reset Mac terminal environment to factory settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692581/is-there-any-way-to-reset-mac-terminal-environment-to-factory-settings)

But I get the same same message that `-bash: rm: command not found`

I can't even open my `profile_bash` file. Is there anyway to reset the terminal to factory settings. Nothing is working in terminal.

Comment: Try `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:`

Comment: For investigation purposes, start Finder app, then navigate to your HOME directory. If you see a file named `.bashrc`, rename it to `.bashrc.bak`. Then open another Terminal, if you can type `ls` now, that mean something in .bashrc corrupted $PATH.

Comment: When using the above command by @YuriGinsburg, it seems to work, but after restarting my Mac, the same issues happen.

Comment: @Philippe I dont see this file

Comment: @GurmukhSingh So, when you make it work, add this command to your `.bashrc` file  i there is no file, create it. Then you can restart a computer if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to reset it:

1. Open Mac terminal
2. Click "shell", it's on the task bar at the top of the screen
3. Navigate to "New Command" or press the keys shift + command + N
4. Type `mv .bashrc .bashrc.bak` redo the same thing for `.bash_profile`
5. Now restart your terminal. It should work fine!

Try recreating but files your renamed earlier by `touch .bashrc` same for `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks folks for contributions. Just like @Yuri Ginsburg said. `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:`.

The following are steps i used to fix back `ZSH` terminal and to make sure all commands are working such as `brew`, `pwd`, `ls` and more.

> How I solved the issue and be able to run all commands again? I tried the following trick.

#### Step 1:

Open your terminal and type `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:`

Please don't close or restart the terminal cause it will fail again. Instead do the following.

#### Step 2:

Open your `.zshrc` file like this `open ~/.zshrc` and add the same command we used in step 1. After go to the opened text file and modify it accordingly.

```sh
# my configuration so yours might different. Try to comment most un trusted and un comment one at time.

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
# PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"
# PATH="/Users/niyongabo/Library/Python/3.8/bin"
```

> Notice that i did export the same command and commented other paths. The reason is that I don't know what's going so I rather un comment later when everything get back to normal

#### Step 3:

Save the file and go back to your terminal and write this command `source ~/.zshrc` to load the changes to terminal.

I hope you can fix back the issue.

macOS Monterey

Answer (score 0):

accessing the directory /Library/Preferencia/com.apple.Terminal.plist

let's change the initial shell of the terminal if it is zsh put csh which is the default shell then go to the terminal in the settings also change the initial shell by csh and restart the terminal . then you can change the shell to zsh and configure